# Would a carbon fiber fork make a significant difference?

Tags: carbon

I have a Giant Escape 2012 that i love.  I ride it more than my road bike. Ive recently switched from 32mm to 28mm tires and can notice the improved handling and speed. Is a carbon fiber fork a good upgrade? I'm mainly looking for upgrades to make my bike lighter. Also, what size would I need? I cant find my bike specs online.

Comment: So, how much lighter would it make the bike?

Comment: Not sure of the exact size for that bike.  Best bet is to pull what you have and measure it.  Carbon will be a little lighter and ride nicer.  Look for a CX 700 to allow bigger tires and center pull brakes.  But a nice carbon fork is $200+ and that is approaching the cost of the bike.

Comment: While the bike itself is not heavy, its also not light. Why do you want to save weight?

Comment: Its more likely you changed brands or models of tyre, and the new ones have better suppleness than the previous ones.  Its less likely that the improvements can be attributed directly to the drop in tyre width.

Comment: Forget the fork - if you want to go faster, upgrading the wheels will give you the most bang for the buck. But looking at the Giant Escape, I'm not sure if it's even worth upgrading. I'd wait until you have a little more cash to spend, and then trade it in for a road bike.

Comment: @MikeBaranczak He says "I ride it more than my road bike", so he's already got one. Maybe he could trade them both in for a _better_ road bike, but I think first we'd need to know why he prefers the Escape now.

Comment: I like the escape because of the more upright position. I feel like I commute more than anything. The road bike is fun and I do notice the increase in speed but I dont have the rack etc that I have on my Escape. I like them both but I find myself using the Escape more. My road bike is a Specialized Allez. Dont get me wrong...i love the Allez, i just dont use it as much.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not a good upgrade.

The fork change could save some weight, up to about 400 grams. This is less than difference between full and empty bottle. The ride quality may or may not change depending on your current fork and the replacement.

If you can't look up the specs of your bike, you can always measure yourself, the critical measurements are steerer tube diameter, steerer tube length (new forks come with extra and you are supposed to cut them, just don't get too short one) and distance from fork crown to axle.